# String to double, then back again. (Java)

Tags: java, string, double

I am trying to make a simple tax calculator program in Java, and cant seem to make the calculation work right. In the code I ended up having to turn the JTextField input into a double variable and then a string. For some reason, this does not work and brings up a bunch of errors. I know there must be some sort of simpler way to write this, so any ideas would be appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;


public class TaxCalculator extends JFrame {

    String twelve;
    JTextField input;
    JLabel ans;

    public TaxCalculator() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tax Calculator");
        JTextField input = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel ans = new JLabel("");
        JButton twelve = new JButton("12%");

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(250, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new JLabel("Price of Item:"));
        frame.add(input);
        frame.add(ans);
        frame.add(twelve);

        twelve.addActionListener(new HandlerClass());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TaxCalculator calc = new TaxCalculator();
    }

    public class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            double fnum = Double.parseDouble(input.getText());

            if (ae.getSource() == twelve) {
                fnum = (fnum / 0.12) + fnum;
                ans.setText(Double.toString(fnum));
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What's the full stack trace of these errors?

Comment: there's no problem with ur calculation. the problem is with the redeclaration of your variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you have declared `JTextField input;` as a class variable but also created a local variable of the same name and added it to your JFrame. That is why you're encountering a `NullPointerException` when you perform `double fnum = Double.parseDouble(input.getText());`

Comment: @SPARK Same goes to your `answer` and `twelve` fields. Also in case of `twelve` you should change its type from `String` to `JButton`. Otherwise `ae.getSource() == twelve` would be pointless.